# How to Handle Zeroes in Ratio of Count Variables

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution, ratio

In my discipline, it's common to use the ratio of predators:prey as a proxy for pest control by naturally occurring pest insects and spiders. That means making a ratio of two negative binomial distributions, (which I would then use as the response variable in a GLM analysis with AICc model selection). Since these distributions are independent, that ratio can vary btw 0 and positive infinity, not 0-1 (in practice, my data go from 0-10). This works fine except when either of the values is a zero (yielding infinity or NaN). Most papers seem to handle this by lumping samples together so no zeroes occur, but I want to analyze my data at the scale I collected them, maximizing sample size and resolution of other variables.

Eliminating all Inf/NaN values works, and I get usable analyses, but it sacrifices information (difference between 30:0 and 1:0 samples) in a way that biases analysis towards processes active in samples where both occur. Adding a small value to all numbers arbitrarily sets the scale of ratios in a pretty extreme way. Is there a good solution for this?

Comment: Since taking a ratio obliterates all information about the actual counts, this approach looks unpromising (and clearly is inadmissible in the technical sense of being a uniformly inferior statistical procedure).  Why not model *both* responses simultaneously?

Comment: Could you give some more details of the glm analysis you are using? Which glm family function? Or references to some papers using this?

Comment: @kjetil 
Here's the paper I'm using as a point of reference, though this is not an uncommon approach in the field: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1049964416302377

I'm not entirely sure the best family to use--it has the shape of a negative binomial distro but also is non-integer so maybe that's not ideal?

Comment: @whuber I'll look into modelling them both together, that seems like a good solution, other than my unfamiliarity with the technique/functions. Is glm.nb capable of handling multiple response vars or do I need something fancier?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a joint model for the two species counts, using a bivariate negative binomial distribution. That could be more informative than analyzing the ratio, as hinted in a comment by user whuber. Now, there are multiple bivariate negative binomial distributions, some papers are [Characterization of the Bivariate Negative Binomial Distribution](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/84121314.pdf) and [A Classification of Bivariate Negative Binomial Distributions](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-58250-9_15).  A limitation might be not admitting negative correlations.

R has multiple implementations of this, and models based on it. See for instance [VGAM](https://rdrr.io/cran/VGAM/man/negbinomial.html) or [bzinb](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bzinb/index.html).  Also [RMKdiscrete](https://rdrr.io/cran/RMKdiscrete/man/binegbin.html).  I will add an example later.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use predators as response like you have, and prey as offset in your negative binomial model. This way you would keep the ratio without having to model with two dependent variables.

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion! My understanding of offsets is fuzzy but I was under the impression they needed to be constants? Have you seen an example of someone using offsets in this way?

Comment: From my understanding, offsets are there to account for varying "exposure" across observations so to speak. So, by definition, offsets are not constants. In your case you would get a model like this: glm(predators~ x1+x2+xi, offset = log(prey), family = neg.bin). I dont know of any good examples but there are quite a few posts on offets. I do not think offsets can be zero however.

Comment: I thought about this, but it doesnt seem to be a good match.  First, you cant have a zero offset, secpnd, what to do woth cases such as (0,1)? That is prey=0,, predator=1? The number of prey doesnt reallt match the defonition of exposure.